Signing in with OAuth on a Desktop application through a web server
I'm having trouble to design a secure architecture to retrieve an OAuth access token inside a desktop application querying a web app that handles OAuth with Twitch
My web app (dotnet/angular) is fully functionnal and handles OAuth correctly if you connect to my website through a browser.
I'm now creating a desktop app and i want to retrieve this OAuth access token to use it to communicate with twitch directly from the desktop app
My guess is to query my web app to retrieve the AuthorizationUrl, then launch a browser on the user desktop to allow him to log in to twitch through my web app.
Now i'm wondering how i can retrieve this access token on my desktop app, and mostly how i can ensure that this token is not grabed by some middle men or someone injecting queries to pretend to be another user
Maybe my scenario is not how i'm suppose to handle this type of behavior
Twitch also has a implicit grant flow that is meant for desktop application but, from what i understand, the user will have to log in through his browser each time he launchs the application
I can also use the standard OAuth authorization code grant workflow but is it okay to store the refresh token on the user's computer?
Any ideas?
